# beamer theme Madrid with biblatex style=authoryear leads to bibliography position offset (first line indentation)

Tags: beamer, biblatex, positioning, indentation, themes

I stumbled upon this, take a look:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@article{myart,
  author={Author, A.},
  title={My Title},
  journal={A Journal},
  volume={123},
  pages={1},
  year={2018},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage[
            style=authoryear,% whithout this style the theme is working
            ]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references.bib}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\nocite{myart}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: comparison]

By commenting out the `authoryear` style, everything works as expected,
but with the `authoryear` style, the indentation of the first line
of the bibliography is shifted to the left.
Seems to be specific for the Madrid theme.

Is it me or is this a bug?
I would like to use the Madrid theme with this citation style,
in case this is a bug, can I help to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @samcarter who pointed at the label thingy in biblatex I managed to use the bib environment from the `numeric` style with the `authoryear` style. The result looks as I expected `authoryear` to work out of the box:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
@article{myart,
  author={Author, A. and Another, B.},
  title={My Long Title},
  journal={A Very Long Journal Name},
  volume={123},
  pages={1},
  year={2018},
}
\end{filecontents}


\usetheme{madrid}
%\setbeamersize{text margin left=1cm,text margin right=1cm}


\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

% authoryear bibenvironment/original
%\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
%{\list
%  {}
%  {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
%    \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
%    \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
%    \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
%{\endlist}
%{\item}

% numeric bibenvironment
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
{\list
  {\printfield[labelnumberwidth]{labelnumber}}
  {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
    \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
    \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
    \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
  \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
{\endlist}
{\item}


\addbibresource{ref.bib}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\cite{myart}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 3):

The `madrid` uses the `infolines` theme, which sets very narrow margins. If you increase these margins, there will be room to show the bibliography icons:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
@article{myart,
  author={Author, A.},
  title={My Title},
  journal={A Journal},
  volume={123},
  pages={1},
  year={2018},
}
\end{filecontents}


\usetheme{madrid}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=1cm,text margin right=1cm}

\usepackage[
            style=authoryear,% whithout this style the theme is working
            ]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{ref.bib}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\cite{myart}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for since I want to use the Madrid theme. Of course I can use the magic `\setbeamersize{text margin left=1cm,text margin right=1cm}` though, thanks for the hint. I will post an update later today. Wait maybe it is... I'll check later ;-) Currently I think about removing the picture or trying to align the picture so it fits on screen?

Comment: Anyways, is there a reason why the `authoryear` style starts indented to the left (compared to the default)?

Comment: @nox Oh, warsaw vs. madrid was just a typos. the message remains the same.

Comment: @nox The reason it works with other styles but not authoryear is that other styles normally have a label before the entry, so they leave enough room. If you don't want to change the margins, you could also look into biblatex and change the width reserved for the label.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me there (label, biblatex) @samcarter, that was the info I needed. Now I'm not sure whether I should accept your answer. Maybe you want to add that part of information to your answer?

Comment: @nox No, please accept your own answer!